# avoide loop for dot product, matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors and I want to get their dor product without for loop. It would save a lot of time.

Here is sample code.

```
p=1;
C=zeros(100,1);
    r_a_= rand(1,3);    
    r_b= rand(100,3);    
    for it=1:size(r_b,1)
        C(p,1) = dot(r_a_,r_b(it,:)) ;
     p=p+1
    end
```

To avoide for loop and to call dot function only once,     I thought like this

```
r_a=repmat(r_a_,100,1);
C = dot(r_a,r_b) %%%%%%%% But obviously it gives wrong answer
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a matrix multiply, like so:

```
r_a_ = rand(1,3);
r_b = rand(100,3); 
C = r_a_ * r_b.'
```